# Go Interface/Container usage

Tags: interface, go, package

Newbie Go programmer here. I'm writing a package that reads a JSON configuration file. It uses the built-in JSON decoding, of course. But I want it to be able to include other JSON files as well, by looking for an array of filenames with the key of 'Includes'. I got it working as just a function and passing in a struct for the JSON data that includes a slice of strings labeled 'Includes', but I don't know how to specify this as a package.

Here's the function:

```
func ReadConfig(filename string, configuration *Configuration) error {

  log.Println("reading file", filename)
  file, err := os.Open(filename)
  if err != nil {
    log.Println("Can't read", filename)
    return err
  }
  decoder := json.NewDecoder(file)
  if err := decoder.Decode(&configuration); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return err
  }

  includes := make([]string, len(configuration.Includes))
  copy(includes, configuration.Includes)
  config.Includes = configuration.Includes[0:0]
  for _, inc := range includes {
    log.Println(inc)
    if err := ReadConfig(inc, configuration); err != nil {
      return err
    }
  }

  return nil
}
```

Which works with:

```
type Configuration struct {
  Includes []string
  .... other defs
}
```

But, in a package, I want ReadConfig to take any kind Configuration struct, as long as one of its members is 'Includes []string'.

I believe I need to change the ReadConfig def to:

```
func ReadConfig(filename string, configuration interface{})
```

But what I don't know is how to access the Includes slice within that.

Comment: It may be worth noting that APIs that take in a one-method `interface` could be re-written as taking a function type. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63557675/12817546.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create an interface for it

```
type Configurable interface {
    Configuration() []string
}
```

And then provide a `Configuration` *method* instead of a field for your structs, and change the signature of your function to `func ReadConfig(filename string, configuration Configurable)`.

It'd be much easier to just pass in the slice instead of the struct though.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I don't understand your final sentence though. The config data struct is more than just a slice of strings.

Comment: @MarkFletcher What stops you from calling it as `ReadConfig(config.Includes)` rather than `ReadConfig(config)`?

Comment: ReadConfig reads the JSON file into the config struct, which consists of other (possibly non-string/slice) fields besides Includes. Are you suggesting passing in a second argument that's a pointer to Includes within the config struct?