# Basic API in golang antipattern?

Tags: api, design-patterns, go

Correct me if I'm wrong, but for my understanding of an API is that it is something that allows me to modify and request data through an interface,  which is what I want to do in Go. For example I have a user interface:

```
interface IUser {
  GetId() int
  GetName() string
  GetSignupDate() time
  GetPermissions() []IPermission
  Delete()
}
```

This already looks to me like active record and if I want to create a new user with a new id I would have to use `new` since Go doesn't support static functions as far as I know. This means I would also need a commit function in my interface, which makes it even worse for me. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You aren't being very clear here on how you would *like* the API to look. That said, just get used to how Go does APIs and use that. Look at how the included IO modules work with Reader, Writer, and the various kinds of Buffer. Don't try to copy a Java or C# or whatever pattern because it will feel WRONG to every other Go programmer.

Comment: Another comment about adding functions to interfaces. Consider adding another interface. If you need an object to be saved into a database you might have a second interface that does that and then you implement that on your BasicUser structure.

Answer (score 2):

In Go, interfaces are behavioural. That is, they describe what a thing *does* more than what it *is*. Your example looks like you're trying to write C# in Go, with your heavy use of I in front of interface classes. However, an interface that is only implemented by one type is a bit of a waste of time.

Instead, consider:

```
interface Deleteable {  // You'd probably be tempted to call this IDeleteable
                        // Effective go suggests Deleter, but the grammar 
                        // sounds weird
    Delete() err
}
```

Now you can create a function to perform batch deletes:

```
func BatchDelete(victims []Deleteable) {
    // Do some cool things for batching, connect to db, start a transaction
    for _, victim := range(victims) {
        victim.Delete()  // Or arrange for this function to be called somehow.
    }
}
```

You'd probably get started faster by creating an interface for Update, Serialize and so on, and *storing* your actual users/permissions/etc in concrete structs that implement those methods. (Note in Go you don't have to say that a type implements an interface, it happens "automatically"). You also don't have to have a single interface for each method (Updater, Serializable), but you can bundle them all into one interface:

```
type DBObject interface {
    Update()
    Serialize() RowType
    Delete()
}

type User struct {
    Id int
    Name string
    // ... etc
}
```

Remember, your model can always "Fill in" a User object to return from your API, even if the actual representation of the User object is something much more diffuse, e.g. RDF triples.

Comment: But as soon as I add functions to access and modify the data I would mix up an object and a data structure, which is an antipattern http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/119352/does-the-activerecord-pattern-follow-encourage-the-solid-design-principles
How to resolve this?

Comment: @Vic: Is this antipattern concern of yours a real problem or a problem in some pie-in-the-sky theory? If it's a theory problem ignore it and do what works. Ignore the theory because it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ZanLynx comments. Go’s standard library seems to favour the interface way for APIs.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type S string
type I interface{ M() S }
func (s S) M() S { return s }
func API(i I)            I { return i.M() }

func main() {
  s := S("interface way")
  fmt.Println(API(s))
}
```

It may be worth noting that APIs that take in a one-method interface could be re-written as taking a function type.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func API(f func() string) string { return f() }

func main() {
  f := func() string { return "higher-order way" }
  fmt.Println(API(f))
}
```

As an API author, one could provide both mechanisms and let the API consumer decide the style of invocation. See http://aquaraga.github.io/functional-programming/golang/2016/11/19/golang-interfaces-vs-functions.html.