# Combining or extending interfaces?

Tags: go, interface

I have two interfaces:

```
type Request interface {
    Version() string
    Method() string
    Params() interface{}
    Id() interface{}
}

type Responder interface {
    NewSuccessResponse() Response
    NewErrorResponse() Response
}
```

I would like to make a `RequestResponder` interface which combines both of these. Is this possible, or do I have to create a third interface with all 6 functions?

Comment: It may be worth noting that APIs that take in a one-method `interface` could be re-written as taking a function type. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63557675/12817546.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interface embedding is allowed, as documented in the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types):

> An interface `T` may use a (possibly qualified) interface type name `E` in place of a method specification. This is called *embedding* interface `E` in `T`; it adds all (exported and non-exported) methods of `E` to the interface `T`.

This is done throughout Go's standard library (one example is [`io.ReadCloser`](https://godoc.org/io#ReadCloser)).

In your question, `RequestResponder` would be constructed as:

```
type RequestResponder interface {
    Request
    Responder
}
```