# Understanding interfaces in Golang

Tags: function, go, interface, stdout

I'm trying to understand interfaces in Go. I wrote this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Animal struct {
    Name    string
    Ability string
}

type AbilityShower interface {
    ShowAbility() string
}

func (a Animal) ShowAbility() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s can %s", a.Name, a.Ability)
}

func main() {
    var Dog Animal = Animal{
        Name:    "Dog",
        Ability: "Walk",
    }

    Dog.ShowAbility()
}
```

But when I run with `go run main.go` nothing appears in the console. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: It may be worth noting that APIs that take in a one-method `interface` could be re-written as taking a function type. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63557675/12817546.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not printing the result. Change the main to

```
func main() {
    var Dog Animal = Animal{
        Name:    "Dog",
        Ability: "Walk",
    }

    fmt.Println(Dog.ShowAbility())
}
```

FYI: fmt.Sprintf() returns a string and doesn't print it to standard output

> // Sprintf formats according to a format specifier and returns the
>   resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a string from the ShowAbility method, but not outputting it.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Animal struct {
    Name    string
    Ability string
}

type AbilityShower interface {
    ShowAbility() 
}

func (a Animal) ShowAbility() {
    fmt.Printf("%s can %s", a.Name, a.Ability)
}

func main() {
   var Dog Animal = Animal{
       Name:    "Dog",
       Ability: "Walk",
   }

   Dog.ShowAbility()
}
```

Comment: This cause an "too many arguments returns" because `Printf` return an `(int, error)` and my function want only an `string`.

Comment: I removed the 'return' statement (and the return type) from ShowAbility(), which is why that error doesn't occur in my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using `fmt.Sprintf` which actually works like `Scanf` returning value. You need to assign that value to a variable and print the output.

```
func main() {
    var Dog Animal = Animal{
        Name:    "Dog",
        Ability: "Walk",
    }

    output := Dog.ShowAbility()
    fmt.Println(output)
}
```

If you wants to print when calling the function `ShowAbility()` you can use `Printf` function of `fmt` package.

```
func (a Animal) ShowAbility() {
    fmt.Printf("%s can %s", a.Name, a.Ability)
}

func main() {
    var Dog Animal = Animal{
        Name:    "Dog",
        Ability: "Walk",
    }

    Dog.ShowAbility()
}
```