# Extend interface throughout package

Tags: go, interface

TL;DR: Is there a way to extend an interface, or is there a school of thought on how to handle multiple 'datastore' functions (many models under a package), while creating an interface that can be properly mocked for controller testing.

Long Story: 
I just finished implementing [Alex Edward's blog on organizing database access in Go](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access#using-an-interface), and one of the better solutions that would allow me to create mocks involves creating a Datastore interface.

Under a models package I have codes similar to the below

```
type Datastore interface {
  AllPosts() ([]Post, error)
  CreatePost(p Post) error
}

type DB struct {
  *sql.DB
}

func initDB(...)( *DB) { // Code to initialize DB }

func (db *DB) AllPosts() ([]Post, error) { ... }
```

and then under main:

```
type Env struct {
    DB models.Datastore
}

func main() {
  db := models.initDB(...)
  env := &Env{DB: db}

  httprouter.New()
  r.GET("/posts", PostIndex(env))
}

func PostIndex(env *config.Env) httprouter.Handle {
  return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    posts, err := env.DB.AllPosts()
    ....
  }
}
```

I have everything working, but as I add a User model, I realize that my Datastore interface is growing tremendously (CreatePost, CreateUser, GetAllPosts, GetAllUsers, etc.), and although this won't be a problem for a personal project, I couldn't imagine any medium to large scale application doing this. Is there another way to have multiple models under a single package that can be properly mocked for testing purposes?

Comment: It may be worth noting that APIs that take in a one-method `interface` could be re-written as taking a function type. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63557675/12817546.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could instead use a set of smaller interfaces and still combine them into one if needed.

```
type UserStore interface {
  AllUsers() ([]User, error)
  CreateUser(u User) error
}

type PostStore interface {
  AllPosts() ([]Post, error)
  CreatePost(p Post) error
}

type DataStore interface {
  UserStore
  PostStore
}
```

This allows you to mock, say, only `UserStore` in a test. [See the "Embedding" chapter in Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) for more info.

Comment: I am embarrassed at how easy that was. Thank you so much!