# Implementing interface from different package golang

Tags: go, interface, package, implementation

I'm having some issues trying to implement an interface, defined in a different package in golang. I have made a minimal recreation of the problem below

Interface:

```
package interfaces

type Interface interface {
    do(param int) int
}
```

Implementation:

```
package implementations

type Implementation struct{}

func (implementation *Implementation) do(param int) int {
    return param
}
```

Main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "test/implementing-interface-in-different-package/implementations"
    "test/implementing-interface-in-different-package/interfaces"
)

func main() {
    var interfaceImpl interfaces.Interface
    interfaceImpl = &implementations.Implementation{}
}
```

Error message:

```
test/implementing-interface-in-different-package
./main.go:10:16: cannot use implementations.Implementation literal (type 
implementations.Implementation) as type interfaces.Interface in assignment:
    implementations.Implementation does not implement interfaces.Interface (missing interfaces.do method)
            have implementations.do(int) int
            want interfaces.do(int) int
```

Is it possible to implement an interface from a different package?

Thanks!

Comment: It may be worth noting that APIs that take in a one-method `interface` could be re-written as taking a function type. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63557675/12817546.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that your `do` function is not exported from the `implementations` package because it starts with a lower-case letter. Thus from the point of view of the `main` package, the variable `interfaceImpl` does not implement the interface because it cannot see the `do` function.

Rename your interface function to upper-case `Do` to resolve the problem.